# How to do delta load using KQL query

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to load the data using Spark connector from an ADX cluster and save it in Azure storage. But the table in the ADX database will get updated every week, So how can I write KQL query to load only the latest data from the cluster and save it in storage?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code for spark connector.

query=
"""
Table
| count
"""

```
dataframe= spark.read. \
        format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource"). \
        option("kustoCluster",        kustoOptions["kustoCluster"]). \
        option("kustoDatabase",       kustoOptions["kustoDatabase"]). \
        option("kustoQuery",          query). \
        option("kustoAadAppId",       kustoOptions["kustoAadAppId"]). \
        option("kustoAadAppSecret",   kustoOptions["kustoAadAppSecret"]). \
        option("kustoAadAuthorityID", kustoOptions["kustoAadAuthorityID"]). \ 
        load()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Database cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databasecursor)

> Database cursors are designed to address two important scenarios:
>
> - The ability to repeat the same query multiple times and get the same results, as long as the query indicates "same data set".
> - **The ability to make an "exactly once" query. This query only "sees" the data that a previous query didn't see, because the data wasn't available then. The query lets you iterate, for example, through all the newly arrived data in a table without fear of processing the same record twice or skipping records by mistake.**